# Geo clustering in python shows weird results

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to make geographical clusters (in The Netherlands) with Python. I used HDBSCAN/haversine and numpy/kmeans2 but I get weird results at both. The clusters are horizontal... Anyone any ideas how to do it right?

[image: Weird clusters on NL]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce your results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code (**include a reproducible code fragment**), I'd assume you did not use the x axis.

Note that the sklearn has the (stupid) behavior of accepting `fit(x,y)` but ignoring y (which is supposed to be labels for classification). This is in contrast to e.g. pyplot.scatter, where you need to pass x and y separately.

X *must* be a matrix containing *both* columns. With haversine, you also need to ensure they are on the correct scale (radians?) And right order (longitude first, or latitude first, this *does* matter - read the documentation because I can't remember this).

But without knowing your code, we can only guess.